# Custom loss function using distance matrix

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

For the loss function of my model, I would like to compare the distance between a predicted result and the true value with the distance between the predicted value and its other nearest neighbour in the reference dataset. I can calculate this value using np arrays just fine, but TF doesn't like me attempting to use this on tensors.

```
def nearest_other_neighbour(y_true, y_pred):
    losses=[]
    
    res_df = pd.DataFrame(cdist(keras.backend.array(y_pred), keras.backend.array(y_true)))
    for i in range(len(res_df.columns)) :
        mycol = list(res_df[i])
        dist_ref_self = mycol.pop(i)
        dist_ref_min_other = min(mycol)
        losses.append(dist_ref_self/dist_ref_min_other)
    
    return losses
```

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/mbsariyildiz/34cdc26afb630e8cae079048eef91865) post which would allow me to calculate the distance matrix using only tensors, but I would still need to iterate over the distance matrix afterwards.

How can I perform these calculations using only tensors? Or is there a way to convert the symbolic tensors into np arrays in the loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for this later: I managed to do it all with TF ops

```
# def create_custom_loss(constant=1.0):
def create_nearest_other_neighbour(mybatchsize):
# def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    def nearest_other_neighbour(B, A):
        na = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(A), 1)
        nb = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(B), 1)

        # na as a row and nb as a column vectors
        na = tf.reshape(na, [-1, 1])
        nb = tf.reshape(nb, [1, -1])

        # return pairwise euclidean difference matrix
        dists = tf.sqrt(na - 2*tf.matmul(A, B, False, True) + nb)

        # extract diag of dist matrix (distance from predicted self to real self), and replace with dummy vals that won't interfere with minimums
        d = tf.linalg.tensor_diag_part(dists)

        newdiag = tf.repeat(tf.reduce_max(dists), mybatchsize)
        dists_nodiag = tf.linalg.set_diag(dists, newdiag)

        # get minimum of each column of new matrix, then divide diagonal by these mins
        # (done in return for fewer variables)
        # min_percol = tf.math.reduce_min(dists_nodiag, 1)
        # dist_ratio = tf.math.divide(d, min_percol)
        # return dist_ratio

        return tf.math.divide(d, tf.math.reduce_min(dists_nodiag, 1))
    
    return nearest_other_neighbour
```

This does require using [datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) to manage your inputs: `train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y)).batch(mybatch, drop_remainder=True)`